# custom h2's all clustered on single div when viewing on mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html

http://jsfiddle.net/RyanHell078/MgcDU/6511/

I am working through my first project using Twitter's Bootsrap. My frontend and CSS skills are fledgling and I am working on understanding CSS and responsive layouts better. I have tried to understand why my H2 classes are not separated when viewing on a smaller display, but they are fine when viewing on a full desktop view.

I like Bootstrap overall, but I am still stuck. I have tried multiple remedies and searched high and low and I am still unable to determine an exact cause or better way to implement the titles for these image divs.

My project is to create a gallery site with 6 image tiles on the homepage (index.html). I will be adding some JavaScript, modals, and tooltips etc later. For now I need to get my layout sharp and working properly.

I decided to use a fluid layout. I created a 'fluid container', then filled it with some rows and spans.My code looks like this:

my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>My Gallery Site</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<!-- Stylesheets -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">



<!-- My Stylesheet -->
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"> 


<!-- responsive fallbacks for apple and ie -->
<!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- Fav and touch icons -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="img/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="img/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="img/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="img/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png">

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- Navigation -->
<style type="text/css">
body { background: black; }
</style>  

<!-- fluid container start -->
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
<!-- horizontal bar top of body -->
    <div class="span12"><a class="brand" href="index.html"> 
            <img src="/assets/images/logo.png"></a>
        <div class="wrapper"><h1><br><p style="color:white;margin-left:20px;">
            Welcome to my Gallery Site</p></h1>
        </div>      
<!-- navbar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
       <div class="navbar-inner">
           <div class="container-fluid">
               <a data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-navbar">

                   </a> <a href="#" class="brand">My Gallery 2013</a>
                   <div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li class="active">
                                <a href="mysiteurl.com/theArtist.htm">Artist</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="mysiteurl.com/artNews.htm">Art News</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="mysiteurl.com/commissions.htm">Commissions</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                 <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Gallaries<br></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Action</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Another action</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Something else here</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="divider">
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-header">
                                        contact me
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <div>
                                        <a href="mailto:myemail@help.com">email me</a>
                                        <strong>my phone number here</strong>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav pull-right">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">resources</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider-vertical">
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Galleries
                                    </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">action</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">another action</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">something else here</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="divider">
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">separated link</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>







<body>
<!-- Main Body Container →
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">

        <!-- span for music -->
        <div class="span4">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="assets/images/music.jpg" alt="music" />
                <h2 class="music">music</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end of span for music -->


        <!-- span for bio -->
        <div class="span4">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="assets/images/about.jpg" alt="artist biography" />
                <h2 class="music">bio</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end of span for bio -->


        <!-- span for new art -->
        <div class="span4">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="assets/images/newart.jpg" alt="new art" />
                <h2 class="illuminatedanddecor">new art</h2>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end of span for new art -->

    </div><!-- end row fluid -->


<!-- ///////////////////   Second tile content row ////////////////////////  -->

    <div class="row-fluid">

        <!-- span for illuminated & decor -->
        <div class="span4">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="assets/images/illumanddecor.jpg" alt="illuminated and decor art" />
                <h2 class="illuminatedanddecor">illuminated &amp; decor</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end of span for illuminated & decor -->



        <!-- span for commissions -->
        <div class="span4">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="assets/images/commissions.jpg" alt="commissions" />
                <h2 class="illuminatedanddecor">commissions</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end of span for commissions -->



        <!-- span for ceramics -->
        <div class="span4">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="assets/images/ceramics.jpg" alt="ceramics" />
                <h2 class="music">ceramics</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end of span for ceramics -->



    </div><!-- end row fluid -->

</div> <!-- /end container fluid--> 

</body>
</html>
```

// My Custom Style Sheet //
/* Footer Border Top */

```
hr.style-one {
border: 0;
height: 1px;
background: #333;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ccc, #333, #ccc); 
background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(left, #ccc, #333, #ccc); 
background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(left, #ccc, #333, #ccc); 
background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(left, #ccc, #333, #ccc); 
}

div.horizontalRule {
clear:both;
width:100%;
background-color:#d1d1d1;
height:3px;
margin-top:10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}


body {
max-width:950px;
background-color:black;
margin: 0 auto;
font color: white; 
}

/* element blocks */
#container
{
height:100%;
width:auto;
position:relative;
}

.image { 
position: relative; 
width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */

}



/* custom h2's for each image tile (div) header */

/* music heading */
H2.music {
background:rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.5); 
text-align:left;
padding-top:77px; 
position: absolute; 
top: 50px; 
left: auto; 
width: 100%;
color: #FFFFFF;
}

/* bio heading */
H2.bio {
background:rgba(170, 187, 97, 0.5); 
text-align:left;
position: absolute; 
top: 50px; 
left: auto; 
width: 100%;
color: #FFFFFF;
}


/* new art heading */
H2.newart {
background:rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.5); 
text-align:left;
padding-top:77px; 
position: absolute; 
top: 50px; 
left: auto; 
width: 100%;
color: #FFFFFF;
}



/* illuminated and decor */
H2.illuminatedanddecor {
background: rgba(170, 187, 97, 0.5);
text-align:left;
position: absolute; 
top: 50px; 
left: auto; 
width: 100%;
color: #FFFFFF;}
}

/* commissions heading */
H2.commissions {
background:rgba(109, 255, 36, .75);
text align:right; 
position: absolute; 
top: 50px; 
left: auto; 
width: 100%;
color: #FFFFFF;}
}

/* ceramics heading */
H2.ceramics {
background: rgba(2, 6, 143, 0.5);
text align:right; 
position: absolute; 
top: 50px; 
left: auto; 
width: 100%;
color: #FFFFFF;}
}

/* end custom headers for tiles */

.wrapper {
background-image: url(http://nwtronix.com/word/assets/images/navbartile.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-size: height="100%" width="auto";
width: 100%;
height: 100%;

}


/* header */









h1 {
font-family: 'Satisfy', cursive;
font-color: '#E5E4E2';
}


/* Copyright */
copyright {
font-color: '#333333';
}

/* Bar Background for H2's */
.bar {
height: 22px;
padding-top: opx;
-moz-opacity: 0.5;
-khtml-opacity: 0.5;
opacity: 0.5;
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
background: black;
border-top: 3px solid #ccc;
border-bottom: 3px solid #ccc;
margin-top: 5.0em;
}

p {
margin-left: 20px;
}
```

For now I have laid out a responsive theme. I created a fluid container. Inside of the fluid-container I created a row fluid, inside of which are 3 span-4’s. There are two rows of these span4’s inside one single container.

I am looking for help with understanding what I am doing wrong with CSS regarding the H2 classes here.

What I did was create some h2 alternatives for each image tile (div). The H2’s define the way I want each title’s title to be. Since the tile’s titles will be on varying background images, I think I need to be able to uniquely position the titles depending on each image. I hoped to use some background opacities to help the titles pop out a bit more from their background images.

My understanding is a custom h2 selector will allow me to create unique styles for any div that I select the custom h2 style inside of. Why the h2 styles are all staying linked when viewing on a small screen is stumping me.

Why are my H2’s all clustered on one single image tile div, when I view in a small display? What am I missing or messing up. I appreciate any and all help and will +1 the best answer.

Thank you

Comment: A link would be worth a thousand words here. Sounds like some @media rules are kicking in on mobile.

Comment: Hi there @NathanHale1996 ... why don't you put this code in a jsFiddle for us so you can help us help you better. I also think that it's just an `@media` query kicking in... but seeing what you are seeing makes all the difference.

Comment: OK, so I think I have it recreated for all intents and purposes. If you shrink the browser/view window, you will see the h2's get collapsed into a single div or element. http://jsfiddle.net/RyanHell078/MgcDU/6511/